# Other ado.net entityframework version or alternatives

Tags: c#, wpf, winforms, ado.net

From several years iam using ado.net to interact with database without any problem. Suddenly everyone see ado.net entity framework came. Personally I feel it is still weak and need much more improvement like making inner/outer join queries. So my question is that, is ado.net still alive with more improvements or I have to move to entityframework? Or is there any other alternative? I use winforms and wpf for development, thanks

Comment: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ee941658.aspx see this link which means ado.net is still in works but I need comments from you people, thanks.

Answer (score 0):

ADO.NET is core concept and also used in some way internally in Entity framework. It is still alive but Entity framework as ORM fits more to object oriented concepts. But you can still use ADO.NET. Also you could use other ORM such as nHibernate.